# setBookmarkExclude on a shiny app with DT data table?

Tags: shiny

If I have a shiny app and I have a DT data table, it will end up creating very long URL bookmarks and I was interested in using setBookmarkExclude to try to remove it

There are several fields that get really long like  `table_row_last_clicked` `table_rows_selected` `table_cell_all` which makes the URL prohibitively long! Excluding simple things like slider1 works though

[http://shinyapp/?*inputs*&slider2=50&table_cell_clicked=%7B%22row%22%3A6%2C%22col%22%3A0%2C%22value%22%3A%226%22%7D&table_row_last_clicked=6&table_rows_all=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D&table_rows_selected=6&table_search=%22%22&table_state=null](http://shinyapp/?_inputs_&slider2=50&table_cell_clicked=%7B%22row%22%3A6%2C%22col%22%3A0%2C%22value%22%3A%226%22%7D&table_row_last_clicked=6&table_rows_all=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D&table_rows_selected=6&table_search=%22%22&table_state=null)

```
ui = function(request) {
    fluidPage(
        titlePanel('test bookmarks'),
        sliderInput('slider1', 'Slider 1', 1, 100, 50),
        sliderInput('slider2', 'Slider 2', 1, 100, 50),
        DT::dataTableOutput('table')
    )
}

server = function(input, output, session) {
    setBookmarkExclude('table')
    setBookmarkExclude('slider1')
    output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
        data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
    })

    observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected, {
        session$doBookmark()
    })
    onBookmarked(function(url) {
        updateQueryString(url)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = 'url')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

- you can only call `setBookmarkExclude` once, you should pass all the names of the inputs to exclude then, as a character vector.
- DT will always store those as inputs, so you know their names a priori. Why not just do:

  `setBookmarkExclude(c('slider1', "table_rows_current", "table_cell_clicked",
  "table_search", "table_rows_selected", "table_rows_all", "table_state"))`

Comment: Thanks for this! It seems to work! If it can only be called once, are there any good strategies to handle this inside a shiny module?

Comment: I think you can include it once in the main server function and once in each module server function. The main app then combines all those together under the hood. From the `setBookmarkExclude` documentation:
This function can also be called from a module's server function, in which case it will exclude inputs with the specified names, from that module. It will not affect inputs from other modules or from the top level of the Shiny application.

Comment: Hmm, I tried a couple things but I wasn't able to get the setBookmarkExclude to work from within shiny module...I was able to prepend the module ID to the inputs and then call setBookmarkExclude from the top level (i.e. outside the module) and get it to work though...


Here are a couple things that I tried in case it helps https://gist.github.com/cmdcolin/81fd53540f7cdb393991e164401839af

Comment: There's currently a bug where `setBookmarkExclude` doesn't work correctly from inside of modules, but we have a fix pending: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/1599